# Angular 2 : Writing style tags in angular 2 template

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using angular 2 and angular cli.
I'm trying to write some some style tags inside a component's template. I want to be able to specify the background image, based on media queries.

I cannot put the code directly in css files as the image is stored inside a variable.

I cannot either use a [style.background-image] binding as the background image will be different based on media queries

In the code below, bkgImg is a string variable containing the image's name (e.g. test.jpg), and imageUrl is a pipe that will build the background image full URL, based on a parameter representing the size.

My probblem is that this code is added with all other styles at the end of the document, as is (i.e. angular does not replace the variable with it's value)

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 1600px) {
  .textWrapper
  {
    background-image: url({{bkgImg|imageUrl:'1600x1200'}});
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .textWrapper
  {
    background-image: url({{bkgImg|imageUrl:'1200x800'}});
  }
} 
</style>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot bind to component variables in your CSS like that. You will have to rethink your design.

Comment: What do you mean "this code is added with all other styles at the end of the document"? Who's adding that `<style>...</style>` element to the page: you or Angular?

Comment: @AngularFrance: I think it's angular cli

Comment: If you open `index.html` in your editor (NOT in your browser), do you see the `<style>` tag or not?

Comment: @AngularFrance: no; angular cli adds all the templates  into main.bundle.js